# Double action on anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, scroll, anchor

I am creating video gallery with one main player.

When user clicks on the link the youtube video will play in the main video player. Since some of the videos will appear below the fold I want the page to scroll up so the user can see the main video player.

I need to have double action when user clicks the  tag. 1) open to video 2) scroll up

Is something like this even possible?

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: If you add multiple click handlers with `jQuery`, they'll all run.

Comment: [Tada!](http://jsfiddle.net/wEqS8/)

Answer (score 0):

I've made a simple demo with the functionality you're looking for. Because your video 'link' simply acts as a trigger for on-page events, you don't even have to use an `<a>` anchor element. You could just as easily use a `span`, or any other element (you may also want to replace the `body` selector with a selector for a more specific container element):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#video-link').on('click', function(e) {
        //Scroll the user down to the video
        $('body').animate({
            'scrollTop': $('#video-player').offset().top + 'px',
        }, 400, function() {
            //Start playing the embedded video
            var src = $('#video-player').attr('src');
            $('#video-player').attr('src', src + '?autoplay=1');
        });
    });
});
```

Note that this code triggers the video to play by appending an autoplay tag to the embedded video's `src` attribute, which helps avoid some cross-domain security restrictions that you may run into if you try to trigger the video in some other way.

Also note that this solution schedules one action (e.g. - playing the video) after another (e.g. - scrolling the page). This ensures that the user won't miss any of the video's content while the page is still scrolling as the video is out of view.

jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nzkKv/5/